# Where did people watch trailers before internet was invented?

Tags: cinema-history, trailers

Now, with the Internet, we can simply watch trailers of a film on YouTube or other sites. But how did people watch trailers before all this was created? Were trailers shown in the cinemas only?

Comment: Where are trailers shown today?  The cinema itself, broadcast and cable tv, plus internet streaming sites.  What are you left with when you remove the internet?  I don't mean to sound patronizing, but I suspect this question is getting downvoted because it doesn't take research to answer this question.

Comment: @iandotkelly If this question doesn't fit site rules, I can delete it.

Comment: Primarily cable TV. Trailers are just commercials for movies.

Comment: It fits site rules - I'm just explaining to you why it's its getting downvoted.

Comment: Where did people watch movie trailers? Before the internet, there were movie theaters, broadcast TV, and cable TV.  Before cable TV there were movie theaters and broadcast TV.  Before broadcast TV there were movie theaters.  Before movie theaters there was no place to watch trailers that were not made to advertise movies that were not made.

Comment: I had a VHS cassette full of trailers. So I watched them.

Comment: Next question in the “make everyone feel old” saga will be “where did people watch TV before the internet?”

Comment: @ToddWilcox Lol

Comment: @ToddWilcox It's sad but it's true.  I've already seen people online asking why their phone has letters on each of the number keys.  Even the origins of *texting* is old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where did people watch movie trailers? Before the internet, there were movie theaters, broadcast TV, and cable TV.  Before cable TV there were movie theaters and broadcast TV.  Before broadcast TV there were movie theaters.  Before movie theaters there was no place to watch trailers that were not made to advertise movies that were not made.

Comment: Also, they're called "trailers" because historically they were shown AFTER movies in theaters -- literally "trailing" the movie.

Comment: Also worth noting: trailers were often included at the beginning of rental movie tapes/discs (and even purchase-to-own, sometimes.)  Even that source is rapidly diminishing now, with the rise of streaming and digital distribution.

Comment: @BrettFromLA why do people stay after the end of the movie? Trailers should be shown to people if they're watching. but at the end of a movie, wht did they show trailers when people get tends to leave the theater?

Comment: @Vishwa In the early days of cinema, end credits were a LOT shorter, so audiences didn't have to sit through 10 minutes of them. Filmmakers / studios always put the trailers for new movies after the trailers. It's just how things were done.

Comment: @BrettFromLA but why at the end? which had a huge possibility of people leaving the theatre without looking at them? why not at the beginning?

Comment: @Vishwa I don't know the historical / social reasons. A few thoughts: since this was before television, people only read books and magazines, which didn't have ads at the start, and movies decided to do the same thing. Maybe filmmakers thought that audiences would be so satisfied with the movie that they would stay in the theater afterwards to get "more". Maybe, since there was no television, audiences craved visual advertising and the only way they could get it was in movie theaters. But as said, I really don't know, so I'm going to ask this (on Movies & TV) as a film history question!

Comment: @Vishwa I found the answer [in this article](https://www.historyextra.com/period/20th-century/qa-when-were-the-first-film-trailers-shown/). It's because the first guy to create a trailer (in 1913) put the trailer(s) at the end of the film. Soon, other people started copying what he did, and it just became the industry standard until decades later when some brilliant person decided to show them before the film. Kind of a boring reason, but that seems to be it.

Comment: @BrettFromLA thank you for the detailed comment, I was gonna ask a question but didnt have much time to organize thoughts to ask good question. so in a nutshell, we follow the first guy almost always, no matter that we've changed as society